# Xamarin - Binding .jar libraries

Tags: jar, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-testing, android-espresso

I am working on binding [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/) jar. I followed [these steps](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/), but without success.

**The output:**

```
------ Build started: Project: espresso, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
JARTOXML : warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class org/hamcrest/integration/EasyMock2Adapter : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/easymock/IArgumentMatcher
JARTOXML : warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class org/hamcrest/integration/JMock1Adapter : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jmock/core/Constraint
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Bindings.targets(253,5): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**These are the jars I have included:**

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion, or an idea of what I need to do to fix this, or properly bind Espresso for my project?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before and I have solved it by including the jar file in my android application project. Add it to your root directory with a build action of "AndroidJavaLibrary."